# How to install Oracle Java8 on Ubuntu in June 2019 since Webupd8 Team’s PPA repository does not work

Tags: java, ubuntu-16.04

Installing Java8 using Webupd8 Team’s PPA repository used to work, but now doesn't.

https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-java-8-on-ubuntu/

How are people installing Oracle's version nowadays on Ubuntu?

Update, read this:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: Oracle tag is for tagging question that belogs to Oracle database not to Oracle

Comment: So basically since April 2019 this just won't work anymore, great. Look here if you find this post: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html